# Can a data source in GCP(cloud storage/bigquery table) be assigned as an asset to multiple data lakes or zones, in dataplex?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-dataplex

I have created a big query table, and attached it as an asset, in one of my data lake's zones. I want to attach the same data source as an asset in a different zone, or even a different lake. But, keep running into the error 'Provided resource 'projects/******/datasets/******' is already attached'. I even tried attaching it as an asset under a different project in GCP. But, still got the same error.
I am trying to architect a data mesh using GCP dataplex.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this constraint is to make security and access management predictable.

When a resource is attached to a Lake as an Asset, its access permissions can be configured via the Lake, Zone or Asset. In order to avoid multiple Lakes/Zones/Assets trying to configure the permissions with conflicting policy, this constraint is in place.

Can you describe any details for needing to attach to multiple lakes? That might be interesting to understand to see if the use-case can be solved in a different way or considered for the future as a product capability.

Comment: My use case that I have a bucket per client. Inside the bucket I have "raw" "staging" and "analytics" datasets. It would be nice to be able to have a separate asset for raw files which may be a mix of .csv, .xlsx, .xlsb, .json etc. The curated zone would be for staging and analytics data (parquet datasets, hive partitioned)

Answer (score 0):

You can not attach a GCS bucket or BigQuery dataset to another asset.

As a DPMS can be attached with a lake, There should be 1:1 relationship between lake and DPMS, zone and DPMS database, and underlying storage(GCS/BQ) and assets.

Answer (score 0):

in my use case, the Line of Business called "AAA" is the domain (dataplex lake).

The team identified 3 major business functions within "AAA", that ideally to be regarded in as 3 different zones i.e. "Merchant" zone, "Order" zone and "Fullfilment" zone.

However, the data asset of these 3 zones are seated in the same BigQuery dataset.

It will be really beneficial and cognitively understandable top logically have same dataset be attached into three different zones in this case, do you think so?

thank you for listening.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example. This is good feedback on the need to map resources to domains more flexibly and at more granular level. We'll factor this into the roadmap.

Comment: I want to echo @soonyuan's comment. According to this blog [1], doesn't it mean the same asset can be added to multiple/different Dataplex lakes/zones.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/building-a-data-mesh-on-google-cloud-using-bigquery-and-dataplex/